# Loging and saving to csv

Tags: python, authentication

I'm making login/signing section for my code. I have 2 issues with it. I need help:

1. First question Yes or No functions well until other character entered. While loop is not accepted for some reason. How to get back to beginning until Y or N entered?
2. I would like to store dict with usernames and passwords as CSV file sorted in two columns not rows. How to do it.

Thanks

Here is the code....

```
# CREATING START DICTIONARY     
users = {"guest": "guestpass", "admin": "adpass"}
status = input("\rAre you a registered user? Y / N? ").upper()
while status != "Y" and status != "N":
print ("Please enter Y or N")

# NEW USER 
if status == "N":
   createLogin = input("Create login name: ")
if createLogin in users:  # check if login name exist in the dictionary
        print("Login name already exist! Please, choose another one.\n")
else:
    createPass = input("Create password: ")
    retypePass = input("Retype password: ")
    while True:
        if createPass != retypePass:
            print("\nPassword error!\n")
        else:
            users.update({createLogin : createPass})
            print("\nNew user created! Welcome to ARR!\n")
        break
    import csv

    writer = csv.writer(open('UsersFile.csv', 'wb'))
    for key, value in users.items():
        writer.writerow([createLogin, createPass])

# LOGIN EXISTING/NEW USER 
elif status == "Y":
while True:
        loginName = input("Enter login name: ").lower()
        if loginName not in users:
            print("User doesn't exist! Please enter existing name or sign-in.")
            print("----------------------------------------------------------")
        else:
            passw = input("Enter password: ")
# LOGIN MATCHES PASSWORD
            if loginName in users and passw != users.get(loginName):
                print("Wrong password! Please enter username and password again!")
            else:
                print("Login successful!\n")
                break
```

Comment: This is Python, correct?

Comment: @jkdev Yes... it's Python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In your y/n while loop you are missing a tab to indent the print statement.

2) https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I see so far:

1. Indentation. `print ("Please enter Y or N")` should be indented relative to the `while` statement on the previous line.

   Also, the statement `if createLogin in users` and the following `else` statement should probably be indented one more level, if they are meant to be within the `if status == 'N'` statement.
2. Import statement. Generally, things like `import csv` would be at the top of the file. Try moving it there and see if it helps.